# Title first in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I know this questions has been asked before but the proposed solutions did not work in my case. This is, the bibliography style is different from what I would like to have.

In my text I cite mostly myself with citation numbers such as (1), (2), (3) etc. However, these numbers are not in order in my text as I customized the order in my bibliography according to my needs.

Now, everything works perfectly *except* that in the references the titles of the papers should be first and then the authors. I am not using `biblatex` and use `\bibliographystyle{plain}`. Any idea how I can have the titles in my references first?

Comment: This would involve editing a copy of `plain.bst`. Unfortunately, you'll have to change quite a number of functions (one for each entry type) and the language of the `.bst` files is not particularly intuitive.

Comment: To order citation numbers instead of references alphabetically is just  use `plunsrt` (plain unsorted) instead of `plain`  The titles before the authors is a very unusual format. I cannot remember any bibtex style doing this, but it  is possible *with biblatex* without make a .bst file.